# x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: cannot find -lm

Tags: gcc

I have CentOs 7.9 and installed the scl devtoolset-7. I receive the following errors:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: cannot find -lm
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: cannot find -lc
```

I tried `sudo yum install /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32/libstdc++.a`

and it says it is already installed. I also tried to export the paths below and it didn't help. I am not sure how to solve the problem.

```
export CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc
export CPP=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/cpp
export CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/c++
export LIBS=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/libstdc++_nonshared.a
```

I tried installing the libm and libc packages and the development versions, but it still didn't work.